# Displying Grand Total of groups in Grid

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

i am displaying total value of amount column in a grid view, when i group the grid view it displaiys total of every group but not displaying grad total of all groups sum.How can i display it? i am using ultra grid view in infragistics.

Answer (score 3):

To display the summary for all of the groups you will want to set the [SummaryDisplayArea](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridOverride~SummaryDisplayArea.html) on the UltraGridOverride that has GroupByRowsFooter and a location for it as well.  There is an example in the [Display Summary Footers for All GroupBy Rows](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Display_Summary_Footers_for_All_GroupBy_Rows.html) topic in the help.  The following is the C# code from the help topic:

```
private void customersUltraGrid_InitializeLayout(object sender, 
  Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    this.customersUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowSummaries = 
      AllowRowSummaries.True;
    this.customersUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.SummaryDisplayArea =
      SummaryDisplayAreas.GroupByRowsFooter |
      SummaryDisplayAreas.TopFixed;
}
```